# How to align the list of table with different prefixs

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment

My memory was written in French but an article in English is enclosed in one of the sections. As result the captions of the tables has two styles: "Tableau" and "Table", as shown in the figure attached. Could I possibly align those captions with different prefixes? And furthermore can I modify the space between caption number and caption text? A MWE is provided in the link below.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel} % le langage par défaut est le dernier de la liste, c'est-à-dire français
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document} 
\renewcommand\listtablename{LISTE DES TABLEAUX}
{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
    \listoftables%
}

\newpage

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{Forces volontaires maximales $F_{max}$(N)}\label{table:Fmax}
        \begin{tabular}{c|llll|c|llll}
            \toprule
            Sujets & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Muscles pour FE} & Sujets & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Muscles pour FE} \\
            DT & BB & BR & BL & TB & SHCP & BB & BR & BL & TB\\
            \midrule 
            1 & *1 & & & & 1 & 28 & 9 & 103 & 287 \\
            2 & 86 & 100 & 380 & 1027 & 2 & 314 & 50 & 332 & 925 \\
            3 & 194 & 40 & 113 & 688 & 3 & 59 & 84 & 183 & 650 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \caption{LOOCV results}\label{table:LOOCVresults}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{Muscles} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PCC values $\pm$standard deviations} \\
            & \parbox{3cm}{Crowninshield's cost-function} & Forster's cost-function & KEB cost-function & \parbox{3cm}{EMG-driven method}\\
            \midrule 
            BB & 0.82 $\pm$ 0.13 & 0.81 $\pm$ 0.13 & 0.85 $\pm$ 0.12 & 1 \\
            BR & 0.65 $\pm$ 0.15 & 0.62 $\pm$ 0.17 & 0.65 $\pm$ 0.15 & 1 \\
            BL & 0.45 $\pm$ 0.12 & 0.48 $\pm$ 0.12 & 0.82 $\pm$ 0.12 & 1 \\
            TB & 0.60 $\pm$ 0.12 & 0.66 $\pm$ 0.12 & 0.78 $\pm$ 0.07 & 1 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your `\numberline` redefinition to

```
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\def\tmp{\tablename~\oldnumberline}\zz\tmp}%
\def\zz#1#2{\makebox[1in][l]{#1{#2}}}
```

It is something of a trick that just happened to work.  I pass `\zz` one argument in the redefined `\numerline` and yet define `\zz` to take 2 arguments.  Thus, it grabs the next thing in the input stream for its 2nd argument, which happens to be the table number.  It then sets the combination inside a box. EDITED to regroup `#2` in `\zz`.

Here is the MWE.  The gap between the enumerated table number and the caption will be dictated by how much space was set aside for the `\makebox` (here, `1in`).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel} % le langage par défaut est le dernier de la liste, c'est-à-dire français
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document} 
\renewcommand\listtablename{LISTE DES TABLEAUX}
{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
    \renewcommand{\numberline}{\def\tmp{\tablename~\oldnumberline}\zz\tmp}%
    \def\zz#1#2{\makebox[1in][l]{#1{#2}}}
    \listoftables%
}

\newpage

\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{Forces volontaires maximales $F_{max}$(N)}\label{table:Fmax}
        \begin{tabular}{c|llll|c|llll}
            \toprule
            Sujets & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Muscles pour FE} & Sujets & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Muscles pour FE} \\
            DT & BB & BR & BL & TB & SHCP & BB & BR & BL & TB\\
            \midrule 
            1 & *1 & & & & 1 & 28 & 9 & 103 & 287 \\
            2 & 86 & 100 & 380 & 1027 & 2 & 314 & 50 & 332 & 925 \\
            3 & 194 & 40 & 113 & 688 & 3 & 59 & 84 & 183 & 650 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\def\blob{
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \caption{LOOCV results}\label{table:LOOCVresults}
        \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
            \toprule
            \multirow{2}{*}{Muscles} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{PCC values $\pm$standard deviations} \\
            & \parbox{3cm}{Crowninshield's cost-function} & Forster's cost-function & KEB cost-function & \parbox{3cm}{EMG-driven method}\\
            \midrule 
            BB & 0.82 $\pm$ 0.13 & 0.81 $\pm$ 0.13 & 0.85 $\pm$ 0.12 & 1 \\
            BR & 0.65 $\pm$ 0.15 & 0.62 $\pm$ 0.17 & 0.65 $\pm$ 0.15 & 1 \\
            BL & 0.45 $\pm$ 0.12 & 0.48 $\pm$ 0.12 & 0.82 $\pm$ 0.12 & 1 \\
            TB & 0.60 $\pm$ 0.12 & 0.66 $\pm$ 0.12 & 0.78 $\pm$ 0.07 & 1 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}
\blob\blob\blob\blob\blob\blob\blob\blob\blob
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the goal was to have them right-aligned, change the `[l]` to an `[r]`.  The `[1in]` box size in the `\zz` definition may need tweaking.

[image]

Comment: Well the MWE works but it become weird in my real work. Where it should be Figure 1.1 become Figure 1.             (large space)                  1, do you have any idea which part does it go wrong?

Comment: @jiexiangwen Please see my edit, where I had to regroup `#2` in the definition of `\zz`, which might also fix your issue.

Comment: The problem is fixed now. I will take time to understand how it works. Thank you!

Comment: @jiexiangwen You are welcome.  When asking a question, the way to indicate to other readers that one answer best answers your question is to click the check mark to the left of that particular answer.  That indicates that you "accept" the answer as best.